# warning: format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'pmd_t' [-Wformat]

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel

> /android/kernel/arch/arm/mm/rodata.c:91:4: warning: format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'pmd_t' [-Wformat]
>
> what to end this warning

```
/*


*  linux/arch/arm/mm/rodata.c
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 2011 Google, Inc.
 *
 *  Author: Colin Cross <ccross@android.com>
 *
 *  Based on x86 implementation in arch/x86/mm/init_32.c
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */

#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#include <asm/cache.h>
#include <asm/pgtable.h>
#include <asm/rodata.h>
#include <asm/sections.h>
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>

#include "mm.h"

static int kernel_set_to_readonly __read_mostly;

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA_TEST
static const int rodata_test_data = 0xC3;

static noinline void rodata_test(void)
{
    int result;

    pr_info("%s: attempting to write to read-only section:\n", __func__);

    if (*(volatile int *)&rodata_test_data != 0xC3) {
        pr_err("read only data changed before test\n");
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Attempt to to write to rodata_test_data, trapping the expected
     * data abort.  If the trap executed, result will be 1.  If it didn't,
     * result will be 0xFF.
     */
    asm volatile(
        "0: str %[zero], [%[rodata_test_data]]\n"
        "   mov %[result], #0xFF\n"
        "   b   2f\n"
        "1: mov %[result], #1\n"
        "2:\n"

        /* Exception fixup - if store at label 0 faults, jumps to 1 */
        ".pushsection __ex_table, \"a\"\n"
        "   .long   0b, 1b\n"
        ".popsection\n"

        : [result] "=r" (result)
        : [rodata_test_data] "r" (&rodata_test_data), [zero] "r" (0)
        : "memory"
    );

    if (result == 1)
        pr_info("write to read-only section trapped, success\n");
    else
        pr_err("write to read-only section NOT trapped, test failed\n");

    if (*(volatile int *)&rodata_test_data != 0xC3)
        pr_err("read only data changed during write\n");
}
#else
static inline void rodata_test(void) { }
#endif

static int set_page_attributes(unsigned long virt, int numpages,
    pte_t (*f)(pte_t))
{
    pmd_t *pmd;
    pte_t *pte;
    unsigned long start = virt;
    unsigned long end = virt + (numpages << PAGE_SHIFT);
    unsigned long pmd_end;

    while (virt < end) {
        pmd = pmd_off_k(virt);
        pmd_end = min(ALIGN(virt + 1, PMD_SIZE), end);

        if ((pmd_val(*pmd) & PMD_TYPE_MASK) != PMD_TYPE_TABLE) {
            pr_err("%s: pmd %p=%08lx for %08lx not page table\n",
                __func__, pmd, pmd_val(*pmd), virt);
            virt = pmd_end;
            continue;
        }

        while (virt < pmd_end) {
            pte = pte_offset_kernel(pmd, virt);
            set_pte_ext(pte, f(*pte), 0);
            virt += PAGE_SIZE;
        }
    }

    flush_tlb_kernel_range(start, end);

    return 0;
}

int set_memory_ro(unsigned long virt, int numpages)
{
    return set_page_attributes(virt, numpages, pte_wrprotect);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(set_memory_ro);

int set_memory_rw(unsigned long virt, int numpages)
{
    return set_page_attributes(virt, numpages, pte_mkwrite);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(set_memory_rw);

void set_kernel_text_rw(void)
{
    unsigned long start = PAGE_ALIGN((unsigned long)_text);
    unsigned long size = PAGE_ALIGN((unsigned long)__end_rodata) - start;

    if (!kernel_set_to_readonly)
        return;

    pr_debug("Set kernel text: %lx - %lx to read-write\n",
         start, start + size);

    set_memory_rw(start, size >> PAGE_SHIFT);
}

void set_kernel_text_ro(void)
{
    unsigned long start = PAGE_ALIGN((unsigned long)_text);
    unsigned long size = PAGE_ALIGN((unsigned long)__end_rodata) - start;

    if (!kernel_set_to_readonly)
        return;

    pr_info_once("Write protecting the kernel text section %lx - %lx\n",
        start, start + size);

    pr_debug("Set kernel text: %lx - %lx to read only\n",
         start, start + size);

    set_memory_ro(start, size >> PAGE_SHIFT);
}

void mark_rodata_ro(void)
{
    kernel_set_to_readonly = 1;

    set_kernel_text_ro();

    rodata_test();
}
```

what to do to end this warning , sorry i am not a programmer but i am thinking to be one :D

Comment: the error line is =
 pr_err("%s: pmd %p=%08lx for %08lx not page table\n",

Comment: Where is the function `pmd_val` defined? It returns something of type `pmd_t` (where is that defined?), but your format specifier specifies an `long unsigned int`. Either change the first instance of `%08` to whatever format specifier would be valid for `pmd_t`, change the function `pmd_val` to return a `long unsigned int`, or (if you're sure this should work) simply cast the result of `pmd_val` as `(long unsigned int) pmd_val(*pmd)`.

Comment: i change it to >(long unsigned int) pmd_val(*pmd) but it's an Error

Comment: make[4]: *** [arch/arm/mm/rodata.o] Error 1

Comment: `Error 1` isn't an error message; what does the error message say? Likely you made a typo or some other error.

Comment: /home/mahmoud/Downloads/S860SourceCode/runningKK/android/kernel/arch/arm/mm/rodata.c: In function 'set_page_attributes':
/home/mahmoud/Downloads/S860SourceCode/runningKK/android/kernel/arch/arm/mm/rodata.c:90:58: error: expected expression before '!=' token
/home/mahmoud/Downloads/S860SourceCode/runningKK/android/kernel/arch/arm/mm/rodata.c:90:75: error: expected statement before ')' token
/home/mahmoud/Downloads/S860SourceCode/runningKK/android/kernel/arch/arm/mm/rodata.c:91:4: warning: format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'pmd_t' [-Wformat]

Answer (score 0):

just removed the L 
to be changed to:

`pr_err("%s: pmd %p=%08x for %08lx not page table\n",`

and it **WORKS.** 
thanks @R_Kapp